# Temperature conversion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js, console, unit-conversion

I've made a simple console application using JavaScript, NodeJS and yargs.

#### index.js

This is the startup file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const yargs = require('yargs');
const argv = yargs
.option('celsius', {alias: 'c', default: false})
.option('fahrenheit', {alias: 'f', default: false})
.option('kelvin', {alias: 'k', default: false})
.help('h')
.argv;

let value = argv._[0];

if (!value) {
  console.log('You need to pass a value to be converted.');
} else {
  const convert = require('./convert')

  if (argv.celsius) {
    console.log(convert.fromCelsius(value));
  } else if (argv.fahrenheit) {
    console.log(convert.fromFahrenheit(value));
  } else if (argv.kelvin) {
    console.log(convert.fromKelvin(value));
  } else {
    console.log("You need to pass a valid flag.")
  }
}
```

#### convert.js

This is required by `index.js` in order to transform values. Each scale has it own file.

```
'use strict';

let fixFloat = (value) => parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);

let fromCelsius = (value) => {
  const conversion = require('./celsius');
  let kelvin = fixFloat(conversion.toKelvin(value));
  let fahrenheit = fixFloat(conversion.toFahrenheit(value));
  return `${value}°C = ${fahrenheit}°F = ${kelvin}K`;
};

let fromFahrenheit = (value) => {
  const conversion = require('./fahrenheit');
  let celsius = fixFloat(conversion.toCelsius(value));
  let kelvin = fixFloat(conversion.toKelvin(value));
  return `${value}°F = ${celsius}°C = ${kelvin}K`;
};

let fromKelvin = (value) => {
  const conversion = require('./kelvin');
  let celsius = fixFloat(conversion.toCelsius(value));
  let fahrenheit = fixFloat(conversion.toFahrenheit(value));
  return `${value}K = ${celsius}°C = ${fahrenheit}°F`;
};

module.exports = {
  fromCelsius,
  fromFahrenheit,
  fromKelvin,
};
```

#### celsius.js

```
'use strict';

let toKelvin = (value) => value + 273.15;
let toFahrenheit = (value) => (value * (9 / 5)) + 32;

module.exports = {
  toKelvin,
  toFahrenheit,
};
```

#### fahrenheit.js

```
'use strict';

let toCelsius = (value) => (value - 32) * (5 / 9);
let toKelvin = (value) => (value + 459.67) * (5 / 9);

module.exports = {
  toCelsius,
  toKelvin,
};
```

#### kelvin.js

```
'use strict';

let toCelsius = (value) => value - 273.15;
let toFahrenheit = (value) => 1.8 * toCelsius(value) + 32;

module.exports = {
  toCelsius,
  toFahrenheit,
};
```

You can see it running by [installing it via npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/thermo.js)

```
npm i -g thermo.js
thermo 10 -celsius
=> 10°C = 50.00°F = 283.15K
```

Is my implementation good? This is my first non-web JavaScript program. I want to make the code more idiomatic. I think I messed up some of ES6 variables declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Generalizing code to write less of it

**Adding support for a new time scale**

To test your code for maintainability let's go through a hypothetical situation. What if a new temperature scale were introduced - say [Felsius](https://xkcd.com/1923/)?

To add support for the *up-and-coming* scale you would need to add a new file, `felsius.js`, which will contain 3 conversion functions: `toKelvin` `toCelsius` `toFahrenheit`. Next add `toFelsius` functions in each of the existing temperature scale files.

Alright, lots of maths... but awesome. We did it! Now simply to add:

```
let fromFelsius = (value) => {
  const conversion = require('./felsius');
  let celsius = fixFloat(conversion.toCelsius(value));
  let fahrenheit = fixFloat(conversion.toFahrenheit(value));
  let kelvin = fixFloat(conversion.toKelvin(value));
  return `${value}°ϵ = ${celsius}°F = ${fahrenheit}°F = ${kelvin}K`;
};
```

And add:

```
let felsius = fixFloat(conversion.toFelsius(value));
`${felsius}°ϵ`;
```

To each `fromX` function.

Finally done! Let's reflect:

> Hmmmm... That seemed like an awful lot of work - possibly prone to errors too.

Unfortunately we don't have time for any more reflection because the project manager just informed us of a huge user base that firmly believes in the [Rankine scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine_scale).

**Possible modification**

Having a specialized conversion function between each temperature scale requires \$n^2\$ conversion functions (where \$n\$ is the number of temperature scales you support). You could get by with \$2n\$ if you used a standard temperature scale as the root of all of your conversions. For example **fahrenheit.js** using Celsius as the standard:

```
'use strict';

let fromCelsius = (value) => (value * (9 / 5)) + 32;
let toCelsius = (value) => (value - 32) * (5 / 9);
let toString = (value) => `{value}°F`

module.exports = {
  fromCelsius,
  toCelsius,
  toString,
};
```

Now **convert.js**

```
'use strict';

let fixFloat = (value) => parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);

const temperatureScales = [
  {
    name: 'Fahrenheit',
    file: './farhenheit.js'
  },
  {
    name: 'Celsius',
    file: './celsius.js'
  },
  {
    name: 'Kelvin',
    file: './kelvin.js'
  },
  {
    name: 'Felsius',
    file: './felsius.js'
  },
];

// add conversion code for each temperature scale
module.exports = temperatureScales.reduce((m, fromScale) => {
  const fromTemp = require(fromScale.file);

  // generate the `fromFooBar` function
  m['from' + fromScale.name] = (value) => {
    const standard = fromTemp.toCelsius(value);

    let str = fromTemp.toString(fixFloat(value));

    // generate the rest of the result string
    return temperatureScales.reduce((str, toScale) => {
      if (toScale == fromScale) { // don't recompute the initial temperature
        return str;
      }

      const toTemp = require(toScale.file);
      const temperatureValue = fixFloat(toTemp.fromCelsius(standard));
      const temperatureString = toTemp.toString(temperatureValue);
      return str + " = " + temperatureString;
    }, str);
  };

  return m;
}, module.exports);
```

Eliminating some of the redundancies makes it much easier to add Rankine support. Simply add `{ name: 'Rankine', file: './rankine.js' }` to the temperatureScales list. Then add three functions: `toCelsius` `fromCelsius` `toString` to `./rankine.js`.

Often redundancies in code lead to more work when maintaining. However, the generalized code might be less readable than the redundant version (nested reduce functions - why would anyone do that??).

Nice work overall! For your purpose the redundancies are probably fine -- just some food for thought.

Answer (score 2):

> I think I messed up some of ES6 variables declaration.

Well I don't know if it is really "*messed up*" but you could consider using [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) for any variable that doesn't get reassigned within the current scope. For instance, **index.js** has the line below:

> ```
> let value = argv._[0];
> ```

I don't see any subsequent lines in that file that *re-assign* a value to that variable. So it could be changed to

```
const value = argv._[0];
```

The same is true for the code in other files, like in **convert.js**:

> ```
> let kelvin = fixFloat(conversion.toKelvin(value));
> let fahrenheit = fixFloat(conversion.toFahrenheit(value));
> ```

Those variables also don't appear to be re-assigned, so they could be declared as constants.